# How to remove HTML tags along with id except allowed tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, dom

Here is some sample text:

```
"-A3-<tag1>Sale</tag1>-cum-</blockquote><p <tag1>id</tag1>=\"p_12\"> </p><p 
<tag1>id</tag1>=\"p_13\">        Gift <tag1>Deed</tag1> <tag1>executed</tag1> by C.K. Koshy 
<tag1>in</tag1> favour <tag1>of</tag1> Quilon Diocese         <tag1>and</tag1> C.K."
```

I was wondering how can I remove the `<p>` tags, the `<blockquote>` tags as well as all the `id` but, I want to keep the `<tag>`. Only if the `<tag>` is wrapping around the `p`, `blockquote` or the `id` I want to remove it. Rest all the time it stays. How do I do it in JavaScript? I tried regex with the following pattern:

```
test = test.replace(/<(?!tag\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, '')
```

This did not yield satisfactory results. This is what I am aiming for (The desired output):

```
"-A3-<tag1>Sale</tag1>-cum- Gift <tag1>Deed</tag1> <tag1>executed</tag1> by C.K. Koshy 
<tag1>in</tag1> favour <tag1>of</tag1> Quilon Diocese  <tag1>and</tag1> C.K."
```

How do I get this is JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the `string` as HTML and use DOM manipulation to remove the elements, here is an example:

```js
let input = `-A3-<tag1>Sale</tag1>-cum-</blockquote><p <tag1>id</tag1>="p_12"> </p><p 
<tag1>id</tag1>="p_13">        Gift <tag1>Deed</tag1> <tag1>executed</tag1> by C.K. Koshy 
<tag1>in</tag1> favour <tag1>of</tag1> Quilon Diocese         <tag1>and</tag1> C.K.`

input = input.replace(/<tag1>id<\/tag1>/g, "id");

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');

doc.querySelectorAll('blockquote, p').forEach((e) => {
  [...e.childNodes].forEach(child => {
    e.before(child);
  });
  e.remove();
});

const output = doc.body.innerHTML;
console.log(output);
```

What this does is to first use some regex to make the original input into valid HTML and then go through all the `<blockquote>` and `<p>` elements to extract all the child nodes and insert them before their parents, once that is done, the empty `<blockquote>` and `<p>` elements are removed.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to just remove the ```p``` and ```blockquote``` elements, but I want to keep whatever is inside it. The code that you provided is outputting this ```-A3-<tag1>Sale</tag1>-cum-```. Can you check the desired output in the question? That is how I would like to get it:) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with HTML (or any XML), regex is never the answer. There are way too many gotchas.

Instead, you'll want something like jQuery or Cheerio (which mimics jQuery's API but just contains the stuff for transforming and manipulating HTML without the extra stuff) which understands the actual structure. If you trust the content, you could also dump the HTML into an HTML element with `innerHTML` and access it with `querySelector()`.

Then it is just a matter of selecting the element(s) you don't want and deleting them.

Here is an example using the third option:

```js
const content = '<p>a</p><p>b</p><tag>c</tag><tag><p>d</p></tag><blockquote>e</blockquote>';
const dummy = document.querySelector('#dummy');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

dummy.innerHTML = content;

const toRemove = Array.from(dummy.querySelectorAll('p, tag, blockquote')).filter(el =>
  // for the "element containing certain element" you can't do that with selector along, but can with a filter method
  !(
   (el.tagName === 'P' && el.parentNode.tagName === 'TAG')
     || (el.tagName === 'TAG' && el.querySelector('p'))
  )
);

toRemove.map(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));

output.innerHTML = dummy.innerHTML;
dummy.innerHTML = ''; // empty it out
```

```html
<div id="dummy"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried out but am getting the following output - ```-A3-Sale-cum-``` which not what I expected. i have put in the output that I was expecting. It would be great if you could guide me to the right direction!

Comment: Also, I will take care not to use regex. Since I come from a more Python background, i thought that was the default!

Comment: Regex is useful for a ton of things, just not DOM manipulation.